# RxJava: How resume the work of an observable if a configuration change occurs?

Tags: android, retrofit, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I work with [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/) and [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid). How resume the work of an observable if a configuration change occurs (activity rotation, language locale change etc.)?

I need not only resume the work of an observable, also I need save emitted items, when subscriber is unsubscribed and emit all saved items right away after subscription.

I read a ton of articles, but I didn't find the answer to my question.

I found a few examples, but none of them does not solve the problem:

- https://github.com/alapshin/rxweather
- https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples
- https://github.com/tehmou/rx-android-architecture
- https://github.com/richardradics/RxAndroidBootstrap

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the [`ConnectableObservables`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html). Particularly, [`cache`](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/) or [`replay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) would be handy for this kind of situation.

For example, you can call `cache` on your observable, `unsubscribe` it when activity is destroyed, and resubscribe it again after the activity is recreated.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a demo application (https://github.com/pmellaaho/RxApp) in order to experiment how to tackle these kinds of situations. Basically, I use a singleton model from Activity to get the response from network. This makes it possible to cache responses, access the data from multiple UI components, subscribe to pending request and also to provide mock data for automated UI tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OperatorFreeze from this [library](https://github.com/MaksTuev/ferro) for pausing Observable when activity is recreating. You need pass instance of this operator to method Observable.lift(). You don't need to unsubscribe from Observables when you use persistent Presenter.

Comment: Please declare that you own a resource when posting it. See [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)